# How do I make something happen at a specified rotation which I incrementally go towards and may over shoot?

Tags: unity-game-engine

So I have a script for a day/night cycle attached to the directional light in unity. It slowly rotates the light which creates an effective day/night cycle. There's an event that I want to call once every sunset, or more specifically when the x rotation of the light is at 200 degrees. The problem is my script rotates a little bit each frame, according to Time.deltatime which is obviously not perfectly consistent. Because of this, I might be at a rotation just below 199 and then at the next frame, I might be at a rotation just above 200 degrees, overshooting it so that it's never actually 200 degrees. I tried to get around this by checking if the x rotation is above 200 AND the x rotation - my rotate amount in that frame is below 200, then calling the event. That was the idea but it didn't work for some reason. It never calls the event. Here's my script.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Events;

public class DayNightCycle : MonoBehaviour
{
    public TerrainGenerator terrainGenerator;
    public float dayLength = 3;
    float rotationSpeed;
    public UnityEvent night;
    public float timeNightStarts = 200;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        rotationSpeed = 360 / (dayLength * 60);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (terrainGenerator.mapLoaded)
        {
            Vector3 rotateAmount = Vector3.right * rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
            transform.Rotate(rotateAmount, Space.World);

            float xRotation = transform.eulerAngles.x;

            if (xRotation >= timeNightStarts && xRotation - rotateAmount.x < timeNightStarts)
            {
                night.Invoke();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are facing is expected since Unity uses Quaternions under the hood and quaternion to euler conversions are not stable.

Quote from [Unity docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-eulerAngles.html):

> When you read the .eulerAngles property, Unity converts the
> Quaternion's internal representation of the rotation to Euler angles.
> Because, there is more than one way to represent any given rotation
> using Euler angles, the values you read back out may be quite
> different from the values you assigned. This can cause confusion if
> you are trying to gradually increment the values to produce animation.
>
> To avoid these kinds of problems, the recommended way to work with
> rotations is to avoid relying on consistent results when reading
> .eulerAngles particularly when attempting to gradually increment a
> rotation to produce animation. For better ways to achieve this, see
> the Quaternion * operator.

If you want to avoid Quaternions, you can represent the eulerX angle as a float variable in your code. Increment its value, always set the transform.euler.x from it, but never read it back from the transform. If no other script or physics affects your transform (which should be the case for sun) you will be fine.